# Get specific int from string

Tags: lua

I am new on Lua, the following is a string:

```
...
Test 1
abc 30
bcd 40
cde 50
...
Test 2
abc 30
bcd 40
cde 50
...
```

I wanna get the Int of each Test, how should I managed to achieve this?
any suggestion will be appreciated!!!

Comment: Post your expected output

Comment: I expected the I can sort this string by each Test

Comment: The string is all the lines? Each line? Show what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

Adapt the code below to your needs.  The input string is in `s`.

```
for k in s:gmatch("Test%s+(%d+)") do
   print(k)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally,

```
a = "5"
```

can be converted into `number` using [tonumber](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-tonumber) function.

`val = tonumber("5")` or `val = tonumber(a)`

gives `5` as a `number` from `"5"` which was `string` previously.

Answer (score 0):

Extract numeric part with `string.match` and convert it with `tonumber`.

```
local str = "abc 321"
print(tonumber(str:match("%d+")))
```